# Ubuntu Maven environment variable setting trouble

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

I am trying to set environment variables for JDK & Maven in my ubuntu .profile file . The relevant lines are :

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi

M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3
M2=$M2_HOME/bin
MAVEN_OPTS="MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.23
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$M2:$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/bin

export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export M2_HOME
export M2
export MAVEN_OPTS
export PATH
done
  unset i
fi
```

When I do so , I am unable to run maven , and i have to edit out the maven variables & export them separately on a terminal window.

What can I do to get my maven installation working , while keeping the above mentioned variables in the .profile file ?

Comment: did you `source ~/.profile` after having changed it?

Comment: @JonnyHenly I have updated the .profile contents to mention the for loop. I am also able to execute my .profile .

Comment: @jangroth yes , i did so .

Comment: Why do you need to change your .profile for making maven working? Could you add the error message that you get if you don't change your profile?

Answer (score 0):

why not use the package manager?

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

worked well for me.